# One side colored border

Tags: html, css, border

I recently saw this kind of border ([source](https://dribbble.com/shots/5395283-Admin-Inventory-Management-App-Day-287-365-Project365))
[image]

I am talking about the left, yellow border. What I find special about it, is that it is completely straight on the right side of it, so you could put a vertical line next to it that would either hit completely or not at all any of the yellow part:

[image]

How can one do such a border in CSS? I explicitely do not want to do something like this:

```css
div {
  border-left:5px solid blue;
  border-radius:10px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

If you put a vertical line next to hit, it will hit the edges of the border:

[image]

I hope I described it so one can understand it. Otherwise please feel free to edit this post, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple background will do it:

```css
.box {
 margin:10px;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 border-radius:15px;
 background:                     /*width height*/
  linear-gradient(gold 0 0) left/10px   100% no-repeat,
  #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Another syntax:

```css
.box {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, gold 10px, #f2f2f2 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```